# Is it possible to chain Internet Explorers BasicImage filter with the Gradient filter?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I've tried the following css in IE9

```
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";
```

What happens is which ever filter is specified last is the one that gets applied. Is there any way to rotate the image and correct for opacity?

Comment: I've also tried a filter on each line and not quoting the filter string

Comment: You would separate them by a comma, but I'm not sure whether the end result will be useful. What do you mean by "correct for opacity"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"` both colors are transparent, have you tried a gradient that has color?  Also looking at the [Gradient Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation you should be able to set each filter without commas between them, they do use carriage returns between them though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while so I will show the solution that worked for me. I can't remember why this frustrated me to the point of creating a question on SO in the first place but the following is css that is currently working on my site.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)";
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";
```

The original problem was caused by following what MS recommended which was to put both filters(rotation, opacity) in one "filter" element instead of two. When I had them both in the same element the last command would override the first command. So if I specified opacity then rotation I would get a rotation but no opacity.